# EPSON ePOS SDK TM-T70-i timeout

Tags: thermal-printer, epos

I have a TM-T70-i printer and currently using ePOS SDK v2.3.0. I have a webpage hosted on a webserver, and it sets the IP from the local printer. When I test my webpage on my local, it prints successfully. But when I host the webpage online and connect my local printer, it does not print.

What do you think should be the other alternative solutions?

Comment: What does *it sets the IP from the local  printer* mean exactly? And how is this a programming related question?

Comment: It occur an error of timeout when I inputted the IP address (192.168.0.200). Is it possible to communicate from webserver to localhost?

Comment: 192.168 is a local network. It's not visible anywhere except on your own internal network. Every home network on the planet probably uses 192.168.*, including me. Why are you setting an IP address at all? The browser should be using the printer on the user's machine, and you don't need to know the IP address of that machine. The browser handles all of that for you.